# Android Monitor not showing processes under Device tab

Tags: android-studio, mobile

I have connected my Android phone with a USB cable to my computer. I have opened the Android Monitor from Android Studio. My phone is listed under Device in Android Monitor, but I am not able to see the processes under Device for my phone.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think,Only if the application is in debugged will show under the device.Are you in Debug?

If the app you wish to debug is not listed then make sure that it is a debug build and running on a device.